# C# CefSharp заполнение формы

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vue.js, cefsharp

хочу сделать автозаполнение веб формы, проблема в том что форма на vue.js.
И обычный метод типа этого не работает:

```
var js = @"document.getElementById('Name').value='demoName';"
browser.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPage(js);
```

Данный код работает только если это обычная форма.
Как сделать чтобы vue model заполнялась?

Comment: Так если у вас vue.js рендерит форму, то может пусть он ее и заполняет. Возможно вам скриптом надо не элемент формы искать, а шаблон для вьюхи и писать данные ему в data-аттрибуты? А vue.js просто подуепит эти данные при рендере? Другими словами, ваш запрос запускается до того как отработает vue.

Comment: Как это сделать интересно и как передать данные в data-аттрибуты? Я сначала отправляю запрос с данными на сервер и он мне присылает ответ, только потом мне нужно во vue эти данные сопоставить. Сначала думал может в localStorage записать и через vue извлечь...

Comment: Я думаю слишком низкоуровнево, быть может у вас это можно сделать проще. Ради прикола, а будет ли такое работать `var js = "setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('Name').value='demoName', 500);"`? Кстати, а что такое `ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPage`? Какой-то экстеншн? Что он делает?

Comment: @aepot, ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPage запускает скрипт.   var js = "setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('Name').value='demoName', 500);" - приведет к тому же

Comment: Я знаю `ExecuteScript` и `ExecuteScriptAsync`, а вот `ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPage` - не знаю, и документацию по нему найти не могу. `приведет к тому же` вы уверены? вы смотрели страницу в инспекторе? как выглядит отрендереная форма, есть ли там инпут с нужным вам `id`?\

Comment: ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPage то же как и остальные, только выполнится после полной загрузки страницы. Проблема с рендером, во vue никак не заполнить данные в модель.

Comment: @aepot, id есть. Прикол в том что форма то заполняется, но при отправке их фактический нет. При клике на input сразу теряется текст данных. Нужно вбивать только вручную, проверял с сайтом где всё на js там работает программа корректно, форма заполняется и отправляется.